# How to save grandchild has_many from grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Let's say we have 3 ActiveRecord classes:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :grandchildren
end

class Grandchild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
end
```

When you build a `Child` in the `Parent#children` association, saving the `Parent` creates the `Child`:

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.children.build
parent.save # creates a Parent and a Child
```

And if you have a `Grandchild`, it will save it, too:

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.children.build
parent.children.first.grandchildren.build
parent.save # creates a Parent, a Child, and a Grandchild
```

However, if you already saved the `Parent` and `Child`, you cannot create the `Grandchild` by saving the `Parent`:

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.children.build
parent.save # creates a Parent and a Child

parent.children.first.grandchildren.build
parent.save # does nothing...
```

Is there a way to get `parent.save` to save the `Grandchild`?

(This is not just a theoretical question...  I actually have a reason to do this, and I would rather not have to call `parent.children.each {|c| c.save }`.)

Comment: instead of `build`, why don't you call `create`

Comment: try parent.reload before call to second save.